# Weak Pointer assignment failure

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I am trying to have a shared_ptr to the parent node of a structure within itself. When deriving from such a data type, I want the parent pointer to be casted to the derived type.

Here is the piece of code I attempted to use.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::weak_ptr;
using boost::dynamic_pointer_cast;
using boost::make_shared;

struct A
{
  weak_ptr<A> parent;
  int i;
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : virtual A
{
  int j;
  virtual ~B() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B a, b;
  a.i = 1;
  a.j = 2;
  b.i = 4;
  b.j = 8;

  b.parent = weak_ptr<B>(make_shared<B>(a));
  //                     ^^^
  //                     The problem is here, not where I had 
  //                     thought it was earlier.

  shared_ptr<B> pb;
  if (pb = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(b.parent.lock()))
  {
    // This is the code block that is intended to run
    // but the control does not flow here.
    std::cout << "b's parent: " << pb->i << ' '
        << pb->j << "\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Could not lock shared pointer or Pointer Null" << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output `fails' with the following message

```
Could not lock shared pointer or Pointer Null
```

**Please explain the behaviour**

***Update:***

1. I changed the title, after I learnt from the explanations, that it was actually misleading.
2. To me, The following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016879/weak-pointer-assignment-failure#comment57760790_35016879) from @Igor explain it best.

> `make_shared<B>(a)` creates a temporary `shared_ptr`, which is
>   destroyed at the semicolon. You assign it to `weak_ptr` - but
>   `weak_ptr` alone doesn't keep the object alive

Comment: `make_shared<B>(a)` creates a temporary `shared_ptr`, which is destroyed at the semicolon. You assign it to `weak_ptr` - but `weak_ptr` alone doesn't keep the object alive.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `dynamic_pointer_cast`, you should learn to simplify your code to find the real problem. You would get the same result from `auto p = weak_ptr<B>(make_shared<B>(a)); p.lock();` and if the reason isn't obvious then you need to read about what `weak_ptr` is and what it does.

Comment: I should have thought this through. That is the way I learn I think...

Comment: If your issue was solved with the help of one of the answers,  just remember to accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
b.parent = weak_ptr<B>(make_shared<B>(a));
```

On this line you create a `shared_ptr` which dies on the same line.

The `weak_ptr` only stores a weak reference to it, so it doesn't count as a normal reference that increments the counter.

Therefore when you use the `lock` method of `weak_ptr` it returns an empty `shared_ptr`.

Comment: It is really difficult to say whether God lies in the details, or is it the devil! Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

When you call the following:

```
b.parent = weak_ptr<B>(make_shared<B>(a));
```

The pointer gets destroyed as soon as the weak pointer is assigned, since the weak pointer will not try to keep the object alive.

Rememeber, if there are no more shared_ptr's to an object the pointer will destroy the object and the pointer will become invalid. This is the idea of smart pointers.

Also you are mixing pointer and non-pointer objects, this is bad and can cause issues: Take note, the call to `make_shared<B>(a)` will call the copy constructor of `B` to create a new instance of class `B` that is copied from `a`. So it is not really the parent of `b`, although you want it to be.

I suggest move completely over to smart pointers

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<B> a = make_shared<B>();
    shared_ptr<B> b = make_shared<B>();
    a->i = 1;
    a->j = 2;
    b->i = 4;
    b->j = 8;

    b->parent = a;

    shared_ptr<B> pb;
    if (pb = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(b->parent.lock())) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion(s). They provide me a simple rule of thumb for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
b.parent = weak_ptr<B>(make_shared<B>(a));
```

This line creates temporary shared pointer to copy of `a`, and assigns weak pointer to it to `b.parent`

Then temporary shared pointer is destroyed, making `b.parent` point to destroyed pointer, so any attempt to `.lock()` it would fail.